# Xamarin forms load image from byte[] array is not displaying

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm working on Xamarin forms and I want to load an image from database which is stored in the form of BLOB. So I'm getting string and trying to convert into bytes array and using **MemoryStream** I want to display it. Please find the below code

> This is how I'm converting string format base64 to bytes array

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("imageInBase64Format");
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

> Image Source using MemoryStream and passing bytes array

```
 var ResourceIcon = new Image
            {
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                Source = ImageSource.FromStream(()=> new MemoryStream(bytes)),
                WidthRequest = 30,
                HeightRequest = 20,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            };
```

> I Also tried passing the stream direct to ImageSource

```
var ResourceIcon = new Image
        {
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
            Source = ImageSource.FromStream(()=> stream),
            WidthRequest = 30,
            HeightRequest = 20,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
        };
```

In both the cases I'm not able to display image on the UI.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you set the ResourceIcon? In a ContentPage?